# sql modulo big number

Tags: sql, numbers, modulo

I have a big number, which represent a prelucrated IBAN number. For validate, modulo % 97 must be 1. But...  I got this" The conversion of the varchar value '272429142829272429' overflowed an int column". Code is this:

```
select U.Denumire 
from terti U
where (len(U.cont_in_banca) < 10) and
 (Convert(int, Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace (Replace 
(Replace (Replace (Replace (Replace( Replace (Replace(Replace (Replace( RIGHT(U.cont_in_banca,36) + LEFT(U.cont_in_banca,4), ' ',''),'A','10'),'B', '11'),'C', '12'), 'D', '13'),
'E', '14'),'F', '15'),'G', '16'), 'H', '17'),'I', '18'), 'J', '19'), 'K', '20'),'L','21'),'M','22'),'N','23'),'O','24'),'P', '25'),'Q','26'), 'R', '27'),'S','28'),'T','29'),'U','30'),
'V','31'),'W','32'),'X','33'),'Y', '34'),'Z','35')) %97 = 1)
```

I've also tried casting to `numeric(38, 0)` instead of converting to `int`, but get the following error:

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `convert(int, . . . )` use `convert(decimal(38, 0), . . . )`.  That should be big enough to store the value.